# If $p^n\mid bc$ and $\gcd(b,c)=1$ then $p^n \mid b$ or $p^n \mid c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I try to prove this statement without using the prime factorization theorem.

Let's denote $p^m=\gcd(p^n,b)$ with $p\ge 2$ a prime number, $n\ge 1$ and $1\le m < n$ (if $m=n$ it's ok).

We have that $p^n\mid bc$ so we can deduce by Bézout identity that $p^{n-m}\mid c$.

Now using the fact that $\gcd(b,c)=1$ we can write by Bachet-Bézout theorem : $bx+cy=1$.

Multiplying this equation by $cp^{m}$ we obtain :

$bxcp^m+c^2p^my=cp^m \Leftrightarrow p^nkxp^m+p^{n-m}lp^mcy=cp^m \Leftrightarrow p^n(kxp^m+lcy)=cp^m$

So $p^n\mid cp^m$ and with $n>m$ we can conclude that $p^{n-m} \mid c$ which is useless...

Thans in advance !

Comment: I think in the last step you conclude that $p^{n-m}|c$ which you already have. You need to elaborate more for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last phrase is wrong.

Without prime factorization:

$bs+cr=1$,then $bcs+c^{2}r=c$. $bcs=c(1-cr)$

$p^{n}$ divides $c(1-cr)$. If $p | c$, then $p$ cannot divide $(1-cr)$. Consequently $p^n|c$.

But if $p|1-cr$, then $p$ cannot divide $c$. Then $p^{n}|b$.

Comment: Not sure for your ending

Comment: If $p|1-cr$ and $p|c$, then $p|1$. So, p can't divide c. We know $p^{n}|bc$, clearly $p|bc$, then $p|b$ and p doesn't divide c. Conclusion $p^{n}|b$, because if for any $r<n$ $p^{r}|c$, then $p|c$.

Comment: You have $p^n \mid c(1-cr)$ so $p\mid c(1-cr)$ and $p$ cannot divide both terms. If $p$ divides both it divides $cr+(1-cr)$ in particular. So $p$ divides $c$ or $(1-cr)$. So if $p\not \mid (1-cr)$ we will have that $p\mid c$ and using $p^n\mid bc$ and $\gcd(b,c)=1$ we will conclude that $p^n\mid c$

Comment: @Maman You used Euclid's lemma to know that $p$ divides $c$ or $1-cr$.

Comment: @user236182 You could use that lemma indeed

Answer (score 2):

Induction on $n$:

1. For $n=1$ it holds.
2. (I.H.) Assume that it holds for $n$.
3. Let $p^{n+1}|bc$ with $gcd(b,c)=1$. Then by I.H. $p^n|b$ or $p^n|c$. Assume $b=p^n d$ for some $d$. Then $p|dc$ with $gcd(d,c)=1$. It follows that $p|d$ or $p|c$. Since $gcd(c,d)=1$ we deduce that $p|d$. Finally we have that $p^{n+1}|b$.

Comment: It should be "Since $\gcd(b,c)=1$ we deduce that $p\mid d$" not $\gcd(c,d)=1$ because from $p^n\mid b$ and $\gcd(b,c)=1$ we get $p\nmid c$, so from "$p\mid d$ or $p\mid c$" we get $p\mid d$.

Comment: Euclid's lemma was used in your answer to prove that if $p\mid bc$, then $p\mid b$ or $p\mid c$.

Comment: @user236182 If $gcd(c,d)=r> 1$ then $gcd(b,c)\neq$ which contradicts the initial hypothesis. No need to use Euclid's lemma actually. Note that by using that $gcd(c,d)=gcd(b,c)=1$ it follows that $p|d$. If I am mistaken please elaborate.

Comment: You used Euclid's lemma to know that from $p\mid dc$ we get $p\mid d$ or $p\mid c$.